Why does this character get the disease?
This entire question is a spoiler for NieR Replicant.

In NieR Replicant, I can't understand why Yonah's replicant gets the Black Scrawl. At the end of the game, we clearly see that her Gestalt is still normal (not relapsed into a shade). If her gestalt is not relapsed and Gestalt NieR is still enabling Operation Gestalt to function, then why does replicant Yonah become sick in the first half of the game?

As a secondary question, I'm not 100% sure exactly what happens when she touches Grimoire Noir in the intro and immediately shows the "strange letters". I read something about how the instant you touch the grimoire,

your real body goes poof and a replicant is created in its place,

but that seems like an awfully big leap of logic given the lore.

I’ve made some edits to your post to add more context outside the spoiler markup. If I missed anything that should be hidden, feel free to [edit] it yourself. I’d recommend using spoiler markup sparingly—only for the parts that are really spoilery. Relevant meta posts regarding spoiler protection: [1] [2] [3] [4].

The parts you removed from the spoiler tag gave away the whole ending of the game and what, in my opinion, was one of the biggest wtf moments in a game. Just the way I refer to the characters can in itself be a spoiler. All 5 links you posted as justification were posts by the same user who, while a mod, I don't agree with 100% and neither do others replying to their posts. The disease in question is also whispered about in the lore so it sets up a sense of dread and has an extra impact when the character in question gets it.

There’s no need to hide most of the post under spoiler markup, especially since you already warned readers at the top that the question contains spoilers. Doing so screws up the question summary and forces people to reveal the spoiler just to understand what the question is about. Regarding the meta posts I linked, you’ll notice they’re highly upvoted, which suggests the community broadly agrees with the policy they outline.


Why does [this character] become sick in the first half of the game?

To best understand this, you need to look at lore that is explained outside of the game. The reason the character has the Black Scrawl is because their Gestalt actually did relapse, however they were put into a suspended state.

Due to her Gestalt being suspended in a half-relapsed state, every incarnation of Replicant Yonah will always be infected with the Black Scrawl
Source

According to this Reddit thread, the relapse was halted by putting them into cryo-sleep while they searched for a cure. This is covered in the CD Drama NieR Replicant Drama CD: The Lost Verses and the Red Sky, released only in Japan.
So, with that said, the question is when did they relapse? It happened during the prologue, which is what happened when they touched the book.

When he hurries back to Yonah, she offers him a cookie. Yonah starts uncontrollably coughing, and strange markings begin traveling up her body. She reveals that she also touched the black book in an attempt to help her brother, but her body rejected its power, causing her to to relapse.
Source

